# JavaFX scroll started and ended

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I have a very costly action to do on a mouse scroll on a pane. I currently use

```
pane.setOnScroll({myMethod()}).
```

The problem is that if you scroll a lot it computes everything many times. So what I want is to do my actions only when the scroll is finished. I hoped to use `setOnScrollStarted`, save the starting value and `setOnScrollFinished` to do my actions.

But I don't know why these two methods are never called. As a test I used

```
pane.setOnScroll({System.out.println("proof of action"});
```

and it was clearly never called.

Any idea on how to call my method only at the end of the scroll?

Thanks in advance, A

Comment: The code sample in your third paragraph won't compile, you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: The scroll started and the scroll finished is not fired because they are only fired when the scroll was performed by a touch gesture (not with e.g. mouse wheel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [javadoc of `ScrollEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html) (emphasis mine):

> When the scrolling is produced by a touch gesture (such as dragging a
>   finger over a touch screen), it is surrounded by the SCROLL_STARTED
>   and SCROLL_FINISHED events. Changing number of involved touch points
>   during the scrolling is considered a new gesture, so the pair of
>   SCROLL_FINISHED and SCROLL_STARTED notifications is delivered each
>   time the touchCount changes. **When the scrolling is caused by a mouse
>   wheel rotation, only a one-time SCROLL event is delivered, without the
>   started/finished surroundings.**

**A possible workaround:**

Increment a counter variable every time a scroll is detected. In the listener start a new thread that waits 1 second and performs the action that you want only if the counter equals to 1 (the last scrolling) then decrements the counter.

I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/davidvarga/aac1f9ac3d98aa87daf6bbbe701ef12f), but I copy here the code:

```
public class ScrollablePane extends Pane {
    private Integer scrollCounter = 0;

    private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super ScrollEvent>> onScrollEnded = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super ScrollEvent>> onScrollEndedProperty() {
        return onScrollEnded;
    }

    public ScrollablePane() {
        this.setOnScroll(e -> {
            scrollCounter++;

            Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    if (scrollCounter == 1)
                        onScrollEnded.get().handle(e);

                    scrollCounter--;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            th.setDaemon(true);
            th.start();
        });
    }

    public void setOnScrollEnded(EventHandler<? super ScrollEvent> handler) {
        onScrollEnded.setValue(handler);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            ScrollablePane pane = new ScrollablePane();
            pane.setOnScrollEnded(e -> System.out.println("Scroll just has been ended"));

            root.setCenter(pane);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```